# React Native @microsoft/signalr showing Error : ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: react-native, signalr

**I am Creating Connection like this its working fine before but now its showing error.**

Here is Error I got

```
hub failed ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at HubConnection._startWithStateTransitions$ (HubConnection.js:110)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:294)
    at Generator.next (runtime.js:119)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:63)
```

**Here is my Code.**

```
const createConnection = () => {
    _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(SOCKET_HUB_URL, {
      skipNegotiation: true,
      transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
    })
      .withAutomaticReconnect([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
      .build();
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      _hubConnection.start()
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('hub started', data);
        refreshMessages();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('hub failed', err);
      });
    }, 5000);
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can workaround this by adding:

```
if (!globalThis.document) {
  (globalThis.document as any) = undefined;
}
```

to your app.
See https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38286#issuecomment-970580861 for more context.

Answer (score 0):

**I am able to fix the issue by putting these two lines in start of my function**

```
if (!globalThis.document) {
  (globalThis.document as any) = undefined;
}
```

**like This**

```
const createConnection = () => {
    if (!globalThis.document) {
      (globalThis.document) = undefined;
    }
    
    _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(SOCKET_HUB_URL, {
      skipNegotiation: true,
      transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
    })
      .withAutomaticReconnect([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
      .build();
      _hubConnection.start()
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('hub started', data);
        refreshMessages();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('hub failed', err);
      });
  }
```

**Its a workaround for now and hopefully fixed with Updated Version of @microsoft/signlr**

for more details check following link
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38286